# Lib Files and Defines

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, linker, c-preprocessor

I'm using a couple of external libraries and I'd rather not have to include all their source and header files in my main source directory or in my project file. One option would be to compile the libraries as lib files and link them like that. However **I'm not sure the defines get evaluated before or after the lib file gets created (which one is it?)**. If it's before then obviously I can't just pack them because they might not work properly on different compilers or systems.

So if I can't pack the libraries as lib files, is there any way for me to link in the c or cpp source files? Probably not, since they would have to be compiled first, but maybe I'm wrong.

**Edit:** Here's a follow-up question, based on answers. Do you think it'd be too much of a hassle to have a makefile that creates the lib files? I'd still rather not add the sources to my project or in my source directory.

Comment: You must include the headers to allow compilation of your code which uses libraries methods/defines..

Comment: @Drakosha Yes, do I really have to be explicit so explicit every time? If one's using lib files I guess it's safe to assume they know how headers work. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Library is a binary file, so all defines obviously already in.

Just to make order, defines are evaluated as 1st stage of compilation process - the step is called preprocess. At this stage, for each cpp files created one file containing all `#include`'ed in it files recursively and all macros are evaluated.

Any way 3rd party should not depend on your compilation flags with one exception - release/build lib. Only in this case you need 2 versions of 3rd lib.

As regarding to question if to compile 3rd party libs once or each time while compiling your code it depends. If you are doing it only for itself than do what looks an easies way for you, but if we're talking about development team and the project to be maintain for a long time, than more things are to be considered.

SO we're talking about some solid solution for a team and we want to compile library several times.

In this case I personally strive to compile 3rd part library once and use it many times. This reduces compilation times for each build for each developers, which means faster development.

Nice, but where you hold these libs. I like phisycal separation - 3rd party library and my code not in same tree. This can avoid some not intentional errors. A good build system, and most of time it's mandatory, should be re-buildable. This means that if you checkout your code after year, you can compile and receive exactly same binaries.

Once I used some external read only tree on my machine. This tree was managed only by me. 
To make my sources re-buildable, each next version of 3rd party library put in direcoty containing it's version and my source tree was updated to point to this point. If you build on several machines, than the read only tree should be visible on all these machines.

Additioanal solution is to check if your SCM tool (I suppose you use one) gives you some  ability to combine several sub-tries from repository in one checkhout. For each 3rd party library there's one sub-tree. This way 3rd party libraries are available on all machines your build. I currenly use these method on subversion - it's called svn:external. On CVS AFAIK it's called cvs modules. Additional advantage that the libraries are managed by source control system, so you can track all changes done to 3rd party libs.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Separating my source tree from the tree containing external dependencies is another thing I was trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

`define`s get evaluated even before *compiling*. They are dealt with by the pre-processor, that prepares the code for the compiler to use. So yes, they are evaluated before the libraries are created.

You can't *link* against source code. You can only link with object files, static libraries, or dynamic libraries (shared object files/DLLs).

Using dynamic linking can be a good option, especially if the externals are large and/or you'll be using them in many executables.